# Falha do compilador com código de erro 255. bin\roslyn\csc.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio

> Erro de Compilação
>
> Descrição: Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta
>   solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o
>   código fonte apropriadamente.
>
> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: Falha do compilador com código de erro
>   255.
>
> Mostrar Saída Detalhada do Compilador:
>
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>C:\Dersa\IIS\PatrimonioImobiliario\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
>   /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"
>   ....

Minha aplicação esta esta apresentando esse erro no servidor de homologação.
  No servidor esta instalado a versão 4.5.2 do framework;
  Estou desenvolvendo a aplicação na vs2015 e no framework 4.5.2;

Na minha maquina funcionava normal e esse problema apareceu no servidor de homologação, comparei com uma aplicação que já foi para homologação e não deu problema, a diferença aparente e que o *Micrisoft.Net.Conpilers* estava na versão 1.2.1 e a minha estava na 2.0.0, voltei minha versão para ficar igual e passou a gerar o mesmo erro na monha maquina.

Alguém teve esse problema ou entende melhor o roslyn para me dar uma luz.